# Add parameters to logger

Tags: php, laravel-4

sorry for this stupid question, however, I think my wires get crossed.

I would like to print the parameters `$m`, from the following function in my `log` method:

```
            Mail::send('emails.forgot-password', $data, function($m) use ($user)
            {
                $m->to($user->email, $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name);
                $m->subject('Account Password Recovery');

                Log::info('Mail send.');    
            });
```

How can I do that?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: You could consider Laravel's native way of converting objects to jSON and concatenating it on the message ;)

Comment: @Allendar Thx for your answer! Would you be so kind to provide an example in my case? I would appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either

```
Log::info('Mail send. JSON: '.json_encode($m));
```

or

```
Log::info('Mail send. Data: '.var_export($m, true));
```

or

```
Log::info('Mail send. Message To: '.$user->email);
// and just add whatever variables you want
```

Comment: I tried your last "method", however, I get: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Mail\Message::$to ` any recommendations what I am doing wrong?